# NSURL NSString data "NULL" for SQLITE

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

Could anyone please be kind enough to give a bit of help,

I have been using `- (void)handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)openIn` method to import an emailed sqlite database to the app users, they then use the "open in" option to import the data, the problem I have is the emailed file is becoming too large so instead of overwriting the sqlite file, I would like to append the data to a local sqlite DB (the DB does have 4 tables)

```
dbRMNames = @"fieldnames.sql";
NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
NSError *writeError = nil;
NSString *filePathx = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbRMNames];
[dbimport writeToFile:filePathx atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"Import File Name: %@", dbRMNames);
if (writeError)
{
    NSLog(@"Error writing file: %@", writeError);
}
```

Above is my currant method, I think I need to create a table in the `viewDidLoad`, just not sure how to save the `NSData` to the table.

```
 `- (void)handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)urlx {

databaseName2 = @"KpiPapav2.sqlite";
NSArray *documentPaths2 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir2 = [documentPaths2 objectAtIndex:0];
databasePath2 = [documentsDir2 stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName2];


NSData *dbFile = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlx];
NSString* dbString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dbFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSLog(@"NSString: %@", dbString);


  NSError *writeError = nil;
if (writeError) {
   NSLog(@"Error writing file: %@", writeError);
}
const char *dbpath = [databasePath2 UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &datapapav2) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
    NSString* query =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO kpiRegionCPW (CPW_Region,Region_Number,Region_Name,Regional_General_Manager,Period,EBIT_YTD,EBIT_12Month,Sales_Conversion,Sales_Conversion_VsTarget,PPCR,PPCR_VsTarget,GSHT,Upgrade_Mix,Upgrade_Mix_VsTarget,WCSS,WCSS_VsTarget,Right_Sell_Usage,Right_Sell_Usage_VsTarget,Mystery_Shopper,Mystery_Shopper_VsTarget,SOH_Spend,SOH_Spend_VsTarget,CATI,CATI_VsTarget,Shrinkage,Shrinkage_VsTarget) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"];

    const char *compiledStatement = [query UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement1;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(datapapav2, compiledStatement, -1, &compiledStatement1, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {


        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement1, 1, [dbString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement1, 2, [dbString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement1, 3, [dbString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement1, 4, [dbString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement1, 5, [dbString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement1, 6, [dbString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement1, 7, [dbString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement1, 8, [dbString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement1, 9, [dbString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement1, 10, [dbString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement1, 11, [dbString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement1, 12, [dbString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement1, 13, [dbString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement1, 14, [dbString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement1, 15, [dbString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement1, 16, [dbString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement1, 17, [dbString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement1, 18, [dbString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement1, 19, [dbString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement1, 20, [dbString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement1, 21, [dbString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement1, 22, [dbString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement1, 23, [dbString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement1, 24, [dbString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement1, 25, [dbString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement1, 26, [dbString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);



        sqlite3_step(compiledStatement1);
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement1);


    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }


}

sqlite3_close(datapapav2);
```

}

`
Think I am close, but getting "NULL" data from my NSString "dbString" ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing.  You are binding the same string to 26 columns and the string contains the database path?  What?

Comment: The URL has an sqlite DB file from an email attachment, I am trying to convert the email attachment to a string to update a local sqlite DB, I was successfully overwriting the local copy before, but due to email attachment size, I need to insert the data into the sqlite file on the iPad / iPhone

Comment: So what is binding a string containing a URL supposed to do?  Do you expect it to open the sqlite database pointed to by this URL, extract the row and the correct column and insert that value into the bound variable?

Comment: When you put it like that, I guess I am way off, I thought I was converting the data in the sqlite file attachment into NSData, then NSString & then inserting it into the local sqlite db, are you saying the NSURL will only every contain a path to the sqlite file attachment?

Comment: Yes.  You need to open both databases; read from one and write to the other.  However the whole "e-mail databases about" sounds way off to me too.   Sounds like that data belongs on a server with the clients seeing a small "slice" of the data, but I don't know your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for the response, you have helped a lot, I will revisit my code I guess to use the URL to save the attachment, then some code to open the new attachment & the local version & update, in answer to the local, a number of the users are in places with no wifi or 3G so need to update & access the data offline

Answer (score 0):

Got there in the end after a lot of surfing & reading, code below

```
-(void) updateLocalSqlite {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *maindbPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"newDataPapav2.sqlite"];;

    NSString *newdbPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"KpiPapav2.sqlite"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    char *error;

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:newdbPath]) {

    }
    sqlite3 *database;

    if (sqlite3_open([newdbPath UTF8String], &database)!=SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Error to open database");
    }

    NSString *attachQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ATTACH DATABASE \"%@\" AS aDB",maindbPath];

    sqlite3_exec(database, [attachQuery UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error);
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error to Attach = %s",error);
    }

    NSString *sqlString = @"INSERT INTO kpiRegionCPW SELECT * FROM aDB.kpiRegionCPW";
    sqlite3_exec(database, [sqlString UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error);
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error to copy kpiRegionCPW table = %s",error);
    }

    NSString *sqlString2 = @"INSERT INTO kpiRegion SELECT * FROM aDB.kpiRegion";
    sqlite3_exec(database, [sqlString2 UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error);
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error to copy kpiRegion table = %s",error);
    }

    NSString *sqlString3 = @"INSERT INTO kpiStoreCPW SELECT * FROM aDB.kpiStoreCPW";
    sqlite3_exec(database, [sqlString3 UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error);
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error to copy kpiStoreCPW table = %s",error);
    }

    NSString *sqlString4 = @"INSERT INTO kpiStore SELECT * FROM aDB.kpiStore";
    sqlite3_exec(database, [sqlString4 UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error);
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error to copy kpiStore table = %s",error);
    }

    NSString *sqlString5 = @"REPLACE INTO dataPPR SELECT * FROM aDB.dataPPR";
    sqlite3_exec(database, [sqlString5 UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error);
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error to REPLACE dataPPR table = %s",error);
    }

    NSString *sqlString6 = @"REPLACE INTO storeDetails SELECT * FROM aDB.storeDetails";
    sqlite3_exec(database, [sqlString6 UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error);
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error to REPLACE storeDetails table = %s",error);
    }



    NSLog(@"database update success");
    sqlite3_close(database);

}
```